# Running a script without launch.json when in workspace mode with launch.json files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'd like to be able to run a temporary typescript file without any launch.json file. However, when I go to the "run and debug" panel on the left, it automatically detects launch.json files unrelated to the actively open file and chooses to run those instead.

I want to just be able to run the actively open file without having to define a launch.json.

Comment: wait- why are you going to the run and debug view if you want to run a file without any launch.json file? and why not install ts-node and run in the integrated terminal?